# Html Button Click

Tags: html, vb.net, button

So i basicly made a code to follow people on twitter if i click my button i follow 10 people with 1 click.
No my problem is, if i scroll down in my vb. webbrowser so i get a list of about 200-300 people and i want to follow them with my button
my program doesnt respond anymore. I think because its just too much button clicks with 1 click.
So how can i follow like 1 person then the other one and so on? And not all at the same time?

My Code:

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    WebBrowser1.Navigate("https://twitter.com/YG/followers")
    Dim Rect As Rectangle = Me.WebBrowser1.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle
    Dim BodySize As New Size(Rect.Width, Rect.Height)
    Me.WebBrowser1.Size = BodySize
End Sub

Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32.dll" (ByVal Milliseconds As Integer)

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim allelements As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.All

    For Each webpageelement As HtmlElement In allelements
        '<button class="user-actions-follow-button js-follow-btn follow-button btn small small-follow-btn" 
        'button-text follow-text

        If webpageelement.GetAttribute("className") = "button-text follow-text" Then

            webpageelement.InvokeMember("click")
            webpageelement.InvokeMember("MouseDown")
            webpageelement.InvokeMember("MouseUp")
            webpageelement.RaiseEvent("OnClick")
            webpageelement.Focus()

            If webpageelement.GetAttribute("className") = "button-text following-text" Then




            End If

        End If

    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: if you are using that `Sleep` method, you are *telling* the app not to respond.

Comment: I am not using Slepp i tryed it but didnt work.